# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, http, http-headers

when i am trying to use my NodeJS api from the react app(building a MERN stack app) i get the error mentioned in question
**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)"**

the api is working fine from postman

```
const onSubmit=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(password!==password2){
        console.log('passwords dont match')
    }else{
        const newUser={
            name:name,
            email:email,
            password:password
        }
        try {
            const config={
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }
            }
            const body=JSON.stringify(newUser)

            //axios has been set up as proxy
            //http://localhost:3000
            //we dont need to add the above to url
            const res =await axios.post('/api/users',body,config)
            console.log(res.data)

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.response.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending a very large cookie by any chance? Cookies have a maximum size of 4kb each.

Comment: i am just learning it from a udemy course so not sure how to check cookie size.I did it exactly as the instructor did. Searched google and it told me to clear cookies from browser but that did not help

Comment: its working fine from postman.i get a token back

Comment: Odd. Here's what I would suggest to help debug. On the server side in that route, do `console.log(req.headers)`. Then make the request from postman, then make it from your react app and see what the differences are.

Comment: noticed a weird thing.My nodejs app is set on port 3000 and react app is set on port 5000 but the post request is made on port 5000 despite using "proxy":"http://localhost:3000" in package.json

Comment: That's normal, the request is sent to webpack dev server and the dev server proxies it from there to your node app.

Comment: Actually, try using `http://localhost:3000` for proxy instead. I think you need the full url with protocol.

Comment: i did console.log(req.headers). from postman i get a object with lots of details,but with react app i dont receive anything

Comment: Alright yeah, that means the request isn't getting to your node server somehow. Did you add `http://` in front of the proxy URL?

Comment: Ah, I see lol SO is just encoding it as a link, didn't notice.

Comment: yes,i did http://localhost:3000

Comment: If you're using Chome, check the inspector and see the "Network" tab. Check if that request is actually getting made, and see where it's actually going.

Comment: i dont know how to make anything out of it.it is getting logged

Comment: on firefox i get XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:5000/api/users

Comment: Okay, find the request in the network inspector and click it. Check the "Request Headers" on the right and see if there's anything fishy there. Then check the "Preview" tab and see what is actually being returned if anything.

Comment: preview is white blank

Comment: So that probably means it's sending you an empty HTML page. Let's try and rule out the obvious. Did you restart `webpack-dev-server` after adding the `proxy`?

Comment: Yes its working after restarting.thank you so much for helping me.sorry for wasting your precious time

Comment: No problem! For future record, webpack-dev-server only detects changes in your source code. It must always be restarted if you make any config changes or install a new npm package.

Answer (score 13):

> The HTTP 431 Request Header Fields Too Large response status code indicates that the
> server refuses to process the request because the request’s HTTP headers are too long.
> The request may be resubmitted after reducing the size of the request headers.
> 431 can be used when the total size of request headers is too large, or when a single
> header field is too large. To help those running into this error, indicate which of the > two is the problem in the response body — ideally, also include which headers are too
> large. This lets users attempt to fix the problem, such as by clearing their cookies.
> Servers will often produce this status if:
> The Referer URL is too long
> There are too many Cookies sent in the request

In my case I was sending too many cookies because localhost:4200 was used as the domain of 3 different projects ... The solution (delete useless cookies)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error when I used the same local port in the proxy destination as the port of the React app by accident. This created an internal forwarding loop, resulting in "Request Header Fields Too Large".

Answer (score 5):

I was getting that error when forgetting to run my server first, before running React app.
I used a knex.js and express.js based simple back end and forgot to initialise it before starting React. Now it all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Clean your browser cache or Open with an incognito window.

Answer (score 3):

Go to chrome dev tool > Application > Cookies,
Clear the cookies, and you are ready to rock!

Comment: hey @Sandeep  after following  these step  i am still facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

You must be following Traversy Media !

remove proxy statement from package.json and write node url in axios call

Answer (score 1):

After I used chrispytoe's suggestion to debug, I knew the problem is related to wrong URL, but not axios or React.  To be more specific, something related to the URL on the server side.

> Here's what I would suggest to help debug. On the server side in that
> route, do console.log(req.headers). Then make the request from
> postman, then make it from your react app and see what the differences
> are. –  chrispytoe

How I fixed this problem is to make sure the proxy server port in my client's packcage.json the same as my server.js' port number. Add the line below to the end of your's client's package.json (before the last "}").

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5500"
```

Next, set your server.js' port the same as your proxy's port:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;
```

In addition, it doesn't matter what port you configure your client to use.  It has nothing to do with the server and its proxy server.

Hope my 2 cents help.  Please feel free to correct me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error arises when the API server port you inputted in your front-end proxy(e.g "proxy":"http://localhost:5000/") isn't the same as the port on the server.

Answer (score 0):

when you get back to the front end and start building React hooks, you'll have a to do a bit of jumping around on a PC

install cross-env lib:

```
npm i --save-dev cross-env
```

alter your start  section in package.json

```
"start": "cross-env PORT=8000 react-scripts start",
```

allow you to declare the start port of the project to avoid conflict with other libs, in this case the `create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

[431 HTTP response status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20431%20Request%20Header,size%20of%20the%20request%20headers.) is sent from the server when client's HTTP Header is greater than the server's accepting HTTP Header limit. Maximum size of HTTP Header for well-known web-server is provided [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-of-HTTP-header-values).

This makes complete sense that the API is working fine from Postman and not browser; As there won't be any residue cookies present in Postman.